# C/C++ elapsed process cycles, not including at breakpoints

Tags: c++, c, timer

See the following code, which is my attempt to print the time elapsed between loops.

```
void main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        static clock_t timer;

        clock_t t = clock();
        clock_t elapsed = t - timer;
        float elapsed_sec = (float)elapsed / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        timer = t;

        printf("[dt:%d ms].\n", (int)(elapsed_sec*1000));
    }
}
```

However, if I set a breakpoint and sit there for 10 seconds, when i continue execution the elapsed time includes that 5 seconds -- and I don't want it to, for my intended usage.

I assume `clock()` is the wrong function, but what is the correct one?
Note that if there IS no standard C or C++ single call for this -- well, how do you compute it? Is there a posix way?

I suspect that this is actually information only knowable with platform-specific calls. If that is the case, i'd like to at least know how to do so on windows (msvc).

Comment: sleep does not consume "process time". There is no correct function for your use case.

Comment: expected output is 1 second -- even when ive sat at a breakpoint all day -- the sleep call is really just to give the program a real expected timing

Comment: BTW, there is no language C/C++.  Your post is C++ because `std::chrono` is not in the C language (the C language doesn't have the `::` operator). You should update your tags accordingly.

Comment: Yup, debugging real-time code is tough, because time doesn't stand still when you hit a breakpoint. Too bad. Deal with it.

Comment: Removing all references to sleep, it was a distraction from my intended question. Also mentioning that I will accept any platform-specific example (though ideally windows) way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Since you are targeting Windows, why do you request a POSIX way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, trying to measure the CPU time of your process would be dependent on support from your operating system. Rather than look up what support is available from various operating systems, though, I would propose that your approach is flawed.

Debugging typically uses a debug build that has most optimizations turned off (to make it easier to do things like set breakpoints accurately). Timings on a non-optimized build lack practical value. Hence any timings of your program should usually be ignored when you are using breakpoints–even if the breakpoint is outside the timed section.

To combine using breakpoints with timings, I would do the debugging in two phases. In one phase, you set breakpoints and look at what is happening in the debug build. In the other phase, you use identical input (redirect a file into `std::cin` if it helps) and time the process in the release build. There may be some back-and-forth between the stages as you work out what is going on. That's fine; the point is not to have exactly two phases, but to keep breakpoints and timings separate.

Answer (score 0):

Although JaMit gives a better answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58313965/9005776)), it is possible but it depends entirely on your compiler and the amount of overhead this creates will probably slow down your program too much to get an accurate result. You can use whatever time recording function you please but either way you would have to:

- Record the start of the loop
- Record the start of the breakpoint
- Programmatically cause a breakpoint
- Record the end of the breakpoint
- Record the end of the loop.

If you're looking for speed though, you really need to be testing in an optimized release mode without breakpoints and writing the output to the console or a file. Nonetheless, it is possible to do what you're trying to do, and here's a sample solution.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <intrin.h> //include for visual studio break
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {

    for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
        //Start of loop
        auto start = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        /*Do stuff here*/
        auto startBreak = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        //visual studio only
        __debugbreak();
        auto endBreak = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        /*Do more stuff here*/
        auto end = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        /*Time for 1 pass of the loop, including all the records of getting the time*/
        std::cout << end - start - (endBreak - startBreak) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

given your objective: *which is my attempt to print the time elapsed between loops.*

in the C language:

Note that `clock()` returns the number of clock tics since the program started.

This code measures the elapsed time for each loop by showing the start/end time for each loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void )
{
    clock_t loopStart = clock();
    clock_t loopEnd;


    for( int i=0; i< 10000; i++ )
    {
        loopEnd = clock();
        // something here to be timed
        printf("[%lf : %lf ms].\n", (double)loopStart/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (double)loopEnd/CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
        loopStart = loopEnd;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want to display the actual number of clock ticks per loop, then remove the division by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` and calculate the difference and only display the difference